# difference in training and testing procedure of model

Tags: regression, time-series, machine-learning, estimation

Can anyone please tell me the difference in training and testing of a model. I have developed 5/6 different single pass online learning algorithm (ets, ets+, evolving fuzzy modelling, SOFNN, Gustafson-Kessel, participatory learning). I have collected 3000 pts of data for training and 500 points of data for testing from MG time series in *.mat file in simulink. 
How do the training and testing procedures differ?

Answer (score 1):

Training of the model is the process by which it 'learns' the patterns or behaviours that the model is intended to classify (in the case of a supervised classifier).

Testing of the model is the process by which we determine how the model will operate in the real world, on 'unseen' data.

If you have 3000 data points, then a simple arrangement would use 2000 of those point to train the model and the remaining 1000 to test how well the model can label or classify those data points.

More complex schemes (such as Cross-validation (the name of this site) and Bootstrapping) exist to allow one to reliably estimate how well a model will behave on new or previously unseen data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @bgreene's answer, the testing procedure should use the final model created in the training. So, in your case, you developed 5 (or 6) "final models" in the training data set. Now, in the testing data set, you should run just those final models with the same coefficients, adjustments, parameter estimates etc. that were used in the training.

Comment: so the difference in training and testing of data driven model in regression problem is only of different data set. Any structural change is not required. Kindly verify.

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: and same stand for unsupervised learning.